# ¿como validar que la fecha final no sea menor que la fecha inicial con javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando con dos fechas, una inicial y una final, al momento de guardar los datos del formulario el botón submit no funciona, si me envía el mensaje de que la fecha final no puede ser menor a la inicial, corrige los datos pero ya no hace la función submit, esta es la función que estoy ocupando

```
<script type="text/javascript">
             $("#form").on('submit', function (event) { event.preventDefault(); 
                if ($("#fecha1").val() && $("#fecha1").val() >= $("#fecha2").val()) 
                    { alert("la fecha de termino, no puede ser igual o menor que la fecha de inicio") 
                } });

            </script>
```

necesito que funcione el botón submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso es porque estas haciendo un event.preventDefault del submit y estas sacandole la accion de "submit". Podrias arreglarlo asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $("#form").on('submit', function (event) { 
            if ($("#fecha1").val() && $("#fecha1").val() >= $("#fecha2").val()) 
                { 
                  event.preventDefault();
                  alert("la fecha de termino, no puede ser igual o menor que la fecha 
                         de inicio") 
            }
         });

        </script>
```

En este caso solamente si cumple entra al if, previene que se haga submit y te muestra el alert, en caso de que no entre al if, funciona el submit como funciona normalmente.

Edit: En caso de que quieras validar si es null podrias hacer lo siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $("#form").on('submit', function (event) { 
         if($($("#fecha1").val() != null && $("#fecha2").val() != null){
            if ($("#fecha1").val() && $("#fecha1").val() >= $("#fecha2").val()) 
                { 
                  event.preventDefault();
                  alert("la fecha de termino, no puede ser igual o menor que la fecha 
                         de inicio") 
            }
         });
    } else{
          event.preventDefault();
          alert("Debe completar ambas fechas");
         }

        </script>
```

Comment: me funcionó perfectamente amigo, te agradezco, saludos.

Comment: una pregunta amigo, en el caso de que una fecha pueda ser null, como podría cambiar la condición

Comment: te edito la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Tu script es incorrecto.

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
             $("#form").on('submit', function (event) {  
                if ($("#fecha2").val() <= $("#fecha1")) { 
                   event.preventDefault();
                   alert("la fecha de termino, no puede ser igual o menor que la fecha de 
                   inicio"); 
                } 
             });
</script>
```

Considerando que:

- fecha2: fecha final
- fecha1: fecha inicial

Comment: probé con la opción que me diste amigo, pero en cualquiera de los casos me sigue enviando la alerta.